# Retrieving text outside square brackets in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need some way of capturing the text outside square brackets. So for example, the following string:

```
       My [ground]name[test]Jhon[random]petor [shorts].
```

I m using the below preg match expression but the result could not be expected

```
    preg_match_all("/\[[^\]]*\]/", $text, $matches);
```

it giving me the result which is within the square bracket.

```
    Result : 
     Array ( 
            [0] => [ground] 
            [1] => [test] 
            [2] => [random] 
            [3] => [shorts] 
        )
```

Expect Output:

```
       Array ( 
            [0] => [My] 
            [1] => [name] 
            [2] => [Jhon] 
            [3] => [petor] 
        )
```

Any help that would be great

Comment: Is the last one `petor` or `petor `? Same with `My` and `My `?

Comment: Accepted answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25688889/preg-match-all-for-words-in-and-outside-of-brackets) seems to work fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [preg\_match\_all for words in and outside of brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25688889/preg-match-all-for-words-in-and-outside-of-brackets)

Comment: @nitrin0 That answer is for in and outside of the brackets.

Comment: [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) might have sufficed.

Comment: Your expected output is impossible unless you're manipulating the extractions.

Comment: @Chris Haas, it may be space or may not

Comment: Using that pattern with preg_split will leave also a `.`

Comment: "Retrieving **text** outside square brackets in PHP" - use [`[^\[\]]+(?=\[|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/cIdpWw/1/). Your title does match the body of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the pattern adding `\K` to clean what is matched so far and then using an alternation to match 1 or more word characters.

```
\[[^][]+]\K|\w+
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mfAqNu/1)

```
$re = '/\[[^][]+]\K|\w+/';
$str = 'My [ground]name[test]Jhon[random]petor [shorts].';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r(array_values(array_filter($matches[0])));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => My
    [1] => name
    [2] => Jhon
    [3] => petor
)
```